# MultiValueMap casuing issue application/json;charset=UTF-8 not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

```
class A {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    String name;

    B b;

    //setters and getters
}

class B {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> keyMultiValues;

    //setters and getters
}


@RestController
class MyController {

    @PostMapping(value="/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String doSomething(@RequestBody @Valid A a){       
                 //some business logic

    }

}
```

I am getting below error due to because of using **MultiValueMap** in **B class**
 [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Any idea, how to fix above issue?

Comment: Did you try with some specific implementation in the class B, like a LinkedMultiValueMap ?

Comment: @MarcinErbel Hey thanks a lot, it worked pretty well, after replacing MultiValueMap  with LinkedMultiValueMap , But I didnt understood, why MultiValueMap  didnt worked and how using LinkedMultiValueMap got worked.. any idea?

Comment: So I'm posting an answer. You can tick it as a correct :) Regarding difference is the fact that you need to specify the implementation as your deserializer needs to know it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the interface to implementation on the data class as you need to precisely show to your parser which implementation he should use. In this case, you can use for example LinkedMultiValueMap.